# Parse list of maps or a JSON payload in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I need to parse a list of maps or a JSON payload I get from an API.

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        // decode the json
        for (var i in jsonData) {
          log("i $i");
          propertyList.add(PropertyInformation.fromJson(i));
        }
```

The variable jsonData has this data which is a list with a single element containing several maps.

```
jsonData = [{
addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, 
city: San Antonio, 
state: TX, 
zipCode: 78225, 
formattedAddress: 711 Culberson Ave, San Antonio, TX 78225, 
bedrooms: 2, 
squareFootage: 1340, 
yearBuilt: 1945, 
county: Bexar, 
assessorID: 09296-000-0120, // different position
legalDescription: NCB 9296 BLK LOT 12, 
subdivision: CONV A/S CODE, 
ownerOccupied: true, 
bathrooms: 1, 
lotSize: 7318, 
propertyType: Single Family, 
lastSaleDate: 1999-12-09T00:00:00.000Z, 
features: {
  architectureType: Contemporary, 
  cooling: true, 
  coolingType: Central, 
  exteriorType: Asbestos Shingle, 
  floorCount: 1, 
  foundationType: Pier / Post & Beam, 
  garage: true, 
  garageType: Mixed, 
  heating: true, 
  heatingType: Forced Air, 
  roofType: Asphalt, 
  roomCount: 6, 
  unitCount: 1
}, 
taxAssessment: {2022: {value: 179230, land: 32940, improvements: 146290}}, 
propertyTaxes: {2022: {total: 843}}, 
owner: {
  names: [SANTOS T ESCOBAR, SANTOS MARIA D ESCOBAR], 
  mailingAddress: {
    id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, 
    addressLine1: 711 Culberson Ave, 
    city: San Antonio, 
    state: TX, 
    zipCode: 78225
  }
},
id: 711-Culberson-Ave,-San-Antonio,-TX-78225, 
longitude: -98.539988, 
latitude: 29.382409
}]

      }
```

When debugging and I hover over the jsonData in the for statement, jsonData has the value of
[0]:
Map (24 items)

If I hover over i it contains all of the 24 maps.
0:
"addressLine1" -> "711 Culberson Ave"
1:
"city" -> "San Antonio"
2:
"state" -> "TX"
3:
"zipCode" -> "78225"
I am only showing 4 maps for simplicity.

When execution gets to propertyList.add() it throws an error:
**error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'**

It is only seeing one element in the list and not going into the 24 maps. How do I fix this?

<<<<<  NEW INFORMATION >>>>>
Here is the PropertyInformation you asked for. I have included the entire code that was created by app.quicktype.io as well:

```
class PropertyInformation {
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? formattedAddress;
  String? assessorId;
  int bedrooms;
  String? county;
  String? legalDescription;
  int squareFootage;
  String? subdivision;
  int yearBuilt;
  int bathrooms;
  int lotSize;
  String? propertyType;
  DateTime lastSaleDate;
  Features features;
  Map<String?, TaxAssessment> taxAssessment;
  Map<String?, PropertyTax> propertyTaxes;
  Owner owner;
  String? id;
  double longitude;
  double latitude;

  PropertyInformation({
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.formattedAddress,
    required this.assessorId,
    required this.bedrooms,
    required this.county,
    required this.legalDescription,
    required this.squareFootage,
    required this.subdivision,
    required this.yearBuilt,
    required this.bathrooms,
    required this.lotSize,
    required this.propertyType,
    required this.lastSaleDate,
    required this.features,
    required this.taxAssessment,
    required this.propertyTaxes,
    required this.owner,
    required this.id,
    required this.longitude,
    required this.latitude,
  });

  factory PropertyInformation.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyInformation(
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      formattedAddress: json['formattedAddress'],
      assessorId: json['assessorId'],
      bedrooms: json['bedrooms'],
      county: json['county'],
      legalDescription: json['legalDescription'],
      squareFootage: json['squareFootage'],
      subdivision: json['subdivision'],
      yearBuilt: json['yearBuilt'],
      bathrooms: json['bathrooms'],
      lotSize: json['lotSize'],
      propertyType: json['propertyType'],
      lastSaleDate: DateTime.parse(json['lastSaleDate']),
      features: Features.fromJson(json['features']),
      taxAssessment: Map.from(json['taxAssessment']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, TaxAssessment>(
              k, TaxAssessment.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      propertyTaxes: Map.from(json['propertyTaxes']).map((k, v) =>
          MapEntry<String?, PropertyTax>(
              k, PropertyTax.fromJson(v as Map<String?, dynamic>))),
      owner: Owner.fromJson(json['owner']),
      id: json['id'],
      longitude: json['longitude'],
      latitude: json['latitude'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'formattedAddress': formattedAddress,
      'assessorId': assessorId,
      'bedrooms': bedrooms,
      'county': county,
      'legalDescription': legalDescription,
      'squareFootage': squareFootage,
      'subdivision': subdivision,
      'yearBuilt': yearBuilt,
      'bathrooms': bathrooms,
      'lotSize': lotSize,
      'propertyType': propertyType,
      'lastSaleDate': lastSaleDate.toIso8601String(),
      'features': features.toJson(),
      'taxAssessment': taxAssessment
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      'propertyTaxes': propertyTaxes
          .map((k, v) => MapEntry<String?, dynamic>(k, v.toJson())),
      'owner': owner.toJson(),
      'id': id,
      'longitude': longitude,
      'latitude': latitude,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PropertyInformation{addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, formattedAddress: $formattedAddress, assessorId: $assessorId, bedrooms: $bedrooms, county: $county, legalDescription: $legalDescription, squareFootage: $squareFootage, subdivision: $subdivision, yearBuilt: $yearBuilt, bathrooms: $bathrooms, lotSize: $lotSize, propertyType: $propertyType, lastSaleDate: $lastSaleDate, features: $features, taxAssessment: $taxAssessment, propertyTaxes: $propertyTaxes, owner: $owner, id: $id, longitude: $longitude, latitude: $latitude}';
  }
}

class Features {
  String? architectureType;
  bool cooling;
  String? coolingType;
  String? exteriorType;
  int floorCount;
  String? foundationType;
  bool garage;
  String? garageType;
  bool heating;
  String? heatingType;
  bool pool;
  String? roofType;
  int roomCount;
  int unitCount;

  Features({
    required this.architectureType,
    required this.cooling,
    required this.coolingType,
    required this.exteriorType,
    required this.floorCount,
    required this.foundationType,
    required this.garage,
    required this.garageType,
    required this.heating,
    required this.heatingType,
    required this.pool,
    required this.roofType,
    required this.roomCount,
    required this.unitCount,
  });

  factory Features.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return Features(
      architectureType: json['architectureType'],
      cooling: json['cooling'],
      coolingType: json['coolingType'],
      exteriorType: json['exteriorType'],
      floorCount: json['floorCount'],
      foundationType: json['foundationType'],
      garage: json['garage'],
      garageType: json['garageType'],
      heating: json['heating'],
      heatingType: json['heatingType'],
      pool: json['pool'],
      roofType: json['roofType'],
      roomCount: json['roomCount'],
      unitCount: json['unitCount'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'architectureType': architectureType,
      'cooling': cooling,
      'coolingType': coolingType,
      'exteriorType': exteriorType,
      'floorCount': floorCount,
      'foundationType': foundationType,
      'garage': garage,
      'garageType': garageType,
      'heating': heating,
      'heatingType': heatingType,
      'pool': pool,
      'roofType': roofType,
      'roomCount': roomCount,
      'unitCount': unitCount,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Features{architectureType: $architectureType, cooling: $cooling, coolingType: $coolingType, exteriorType: $exteriorType, floorCount: $floorCount, foundationType: $foundationType, garage: $garage, garageType: $garageType, heating: $heating, heatingType: $heatingType, pool: $pool, roofType: $roofType, roomCount: $roomCount, unitCount: $unitCount}';
  }
}

class Owner {
  List<String?> names;
  MailingAddress mailingAddress;

  Owner({
    required this.names,
    required this.mailingAddress,
  });

  factory Owner.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return Owner(
      names: json['names'].cast<String?>(),
      mailingAddress: MailingAddress.fromJson(json['mailingAddress']),
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'names': names,
      'mailingAddress': mailingAddress.toJson(),
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Owner{names: $names, mailingAddress: $mailingAddress}';
  }
}

class MailingAddress {
  String? id;
  String? addressLine1;
  String? city;
  String? state;
  String? zipCode;
  String? addressLine2;

  MailingAddress({
    required this.id,
    required this.addressLine1,
    required this.city,
    required this.state,
    required this.zipCode,
    required this.addressLine2,
  });

  factory MailingAddress.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return MailingAddress(
      id: json['id'],
      addressLine1: json['addressLine1'],
      city: json['city'],
      state: json['state'],
      zipCode: json['zipCode'],
      addressLine2: json['addressLine2'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'addressLine1': addressLine1,
      'city': city,
      'state': state,
      'zipCode': zipCode,
      'addressLine2': addressLine2,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'MailingAddress{id: $id, addressLine1: $addressLine1, city: $city, state: $state, zipCode: $zipCode, addressLine2: $addressLine2}';
  }
}

class PropertyTax {
  int total;

  PropertyTax({
    required this.total,
  });

  factory PropertyTax.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return PropertyTax(
      total: json['total'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'total': total,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'PropertyTax{total: $total}';
  }
}

class TaxAssessment {
  int value;
  int land;
  int improvements;

  TaxAssessment({
    required this.value,
    required this.land,
    required this.improvements,
  });

  factory TaxAssessment.fromJson(Map<String?, dynamic> json) {
    return TaxAssessment(
      value: json['value'],
      land: json['land'],
      improvements: json['improvements'],
    );
  }

  Map<String?, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'value': value,
      'land': land,
      'improvements': improvements,
    };
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'TaxAssessment{value: $value, land: $land, improvements: $improvements}';
  }
}
```

One problem that I am finding is that not all of the JSON elements are taken care of in the code provided. For example, ownerOccupied is in the JSON passed but is  not found in the code. The website that converted JSON schema to Dart code, app.quicktype.io, used only what was provided in the JSON schema but not all the elements were in the JSON schema.

How do I account for those that are not accounted for in the code?
I don't know if this truly is the problem.

Comment: Can you share your `PropertyInformation`?

Comment: It is the jsonData in the original question.

Comment: No, I mean the model class. How is `fromJson` implemented?

Comment: I agree with @MendelG,  your `PropertyInformation` model class type error.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I added the PropertyInformation or in my code it is the class Items. I hope this will help you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your PropertyInformation class property.
The error is happen when the PropertyInformation have bool variable (not nullable) is assigned by null (from the json).

For example
If your class PropertyInformation have a variable like this.

```
class PropertyInformation{
///other property
bool ownerOccupied;
PropertyInformation({required this.PropertyInformation, /*others property*/})
```

it would be error if ownerOccupied from json data is a null.

To handle the error,
either you need to make the variable is nullable

```
bool? ownerOccupied
```

or assign a default value on the formJson

```
factory PropertyInformation.fromJson(json) => PropertyInformation(
  ownerOccupied: json["ownerOccupied"] == null : false : json["ownerOccupied"]
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited the original post and added the PropertyInformation or in my case, Items. One of the problems I am having is that in your example above, ownerOccupied is not accounted for in the class. How do I account for JSON elements that were not in the schema?

Comment: Add bool? to the right file worked. Thanks